# SQL to DAX Count distinct user who has an active subscription and have logged-in in the 30 days prior on a given day

Tags: sql, powerbi, dax

```
SELECT u.country, COUNT(DISTINCT unique_user_id)
FROM v_user u
LEFT JOIN v_subscription s
USING(unique_user_id)
WHERE '2023-11-25' - u.date_last_login <= 30 and u.date_last_login <= '2023-11-25'
  and '2023-11-25' >= s.date_created_at and ('2023-11-25' <= s.date_ends_at  or s.date_ends_at is null)
GROUP BY 1
```

I have just started using PowerBI, and I'm struggling to translate this logic from SQL to DAX .
I ultimately want to create a measure that works with Date hierarchies, and does this calculation of active user with active subscriptions for any give time period. I already have date table and relationships set up.

Also much appreciated if someone has any advice on how to 'think in DAX'

Edit: added the data model.

[image: data model]

[image: relationship]

Comment: Is `User` and `Subscription` in separate tables or in the one table? If two, what's their relationship. If possible [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77578807/edit) your question with a snip of your model showing the relevant tables and relationships.

Comment: @SamNseir Added the model and relationships

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
User Count v2 =
  var dDate = MIN(calendar[Date])
  var usersLogin30 =
    CALCULATETABLE(
      VALUES(v_user[unique_user_id]),
      v_user[date_last_login] <= dDate && v_user[date_last_login] >= dDate - 30,
      ALL(calendar)
    )
  var usersWithSub =
    CALCULATETABLE(
      VALUES(v_subscription[unique_user_id]),
      v_subscription[date_created_at] <= dDate  && (v_subscription[date_ends_at] >= dDate || ISBLANK(v_subscription[date_ends_at]) )
    )

  RETURN COUNTROWS(INTERSECT(usersLogin30, usersWithSub))
```

And then use `calendar[Date]` for your chart.

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't seem to work. It's vast overcounting, giving 20k+ when it is supposed to be under 1k.

Comment: Updated answer to include `CROSSFILTER(...)`.

Comment: doesn't seem to affect anything

Comment: Have you left `var dDate` as `TODAY()` for now? Try removing `ALL(calendar)`.  How are you using this measure, in which visual? Trying to understand as it should work.

Comment: Updated answer above with an alternative measure. See if this one works. Are there any subscriptions with null `date_created_at` ?

Comment: Yes. dDate was set to Today() for both alternatives. Removing ALL(calender) in v1 resulted numbers in the 10s. v2 resulted in numbers in single digits. result I got from the SQL is 800+

Comment: I'm making a column chart for the days

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256125/discussion-between-sam-nseir-and-nitekat).